# Is it possible to find the source AMI for an existing AMI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

Given a specific AMI, I would like to find the AMI it was originally built from.  I know that an AMI is built from an EC2 instance, but what AMI was it created with?  Is there a way to find out the source AMI?

I cannot find the information I'm looking for in the metadata of an AMI.

Comment: When was the AMI created? The only way I can think of retrieving this is via cloudtrail

Comment: No. There is no 'lineage' kept of AMIs. Can I ask... _Why_ are you asking for this?

Comment: I'm trying to ensure that all instances created are from our "golden AMI" or those created _from_ the golden AMI.